# Why derivation is a directional derivative?

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold, and $X\in T_pM$. Why for every derivation in $p\in M$ exist tangent vector $X\in T_pM$, witch satisfies $L_p(f) = X\cdot f$ for every smooth $f\colon M\to\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1):

To prove this you need the useful lemma that if $U$ is a neighborhood of $0$ in $\Bbb R^n$ and $g\colon U\to\Bbb R$ is smooth with $g(0)=0$, then there are smooth functions $g_i\colon U\to\Bbb R$ so that 
$$g(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_ig_i(x).$$
Moreover, $g_i(0) = \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}(0)$.

Now use the properties of a derivation.

Comment: Ok, so I want to calculate $L_p(f)$ in local coordinates $p\in(\varphi, U)$ and $\varphi(p) = 0\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Right, and $g=f\circ \varphi^{-1}$. You can easily also prove that the value of the derivation on $f$ depends only on $f$ in a tiny neighborhood of $p$.

Comment: Ok, so I want to calculate $L_p(f)$ in local coordinates $p\in(\varphi, U)$ and $\varphi(p) = 0\in\mathbb{R}^n$. $L_p(f) = L_p(\sum_{i=1}^n x_ig_i) = \sum_{i=1}^nL_p(x_i)g_i(p) + x_i(p)L_p(g_i)$. In my coordinates "$x_i(p) = 0$" for all $i$, so I will obtain $\sum_{i=1}^nL_p(x_i)g_i(p) = \sum_{i=1}^nL_p(x_i)\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}(p) = (L_p(x_1), L_p(x_2), \ldots, L_p(x_n))\cdot f$. Is that correct? If it is, than my vector is $(L_p(x_1), L_p(x_2), \ldots, L_p(x_n))$, so I also show, that this is unique. How I should think about $L_p(x_i)$? What is it? $x_i(p) = (\varphi(p))_i$?

Comment: Yes, but my suggestion is to work *in* local coordinates in $\Bbb R^n$, understand the derivation in the setting of $U\subset\Bbb R^n$, and *then* move it over to the manifold.

Comment: Ok, so instead of $L_p(x_i)$ i should write $L_{\varphi(p)}(x_i)$ and after I will do all the staff (after I compute $L_{\varphi(p)}(\varphi\circ f)$) I need to use $\varphi^{-1}$ to go back. I think about local coordinates like this: take an arbitrary point $p\in M$. This point has a (perhaps small) open neighbourhood $U_p\subset M$, witch is homeomorphic to some open neighbourhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\varphi(p) = 0$. So I can think about $U$ like this: take $\varphi(U)$, and put it on $M$ (maby before it you need to smoothly deform it). About $U$ I think like about $\varphi(U)$.

Comment: So about $f$ locally I can think as about $\varphi\circ f$, and that is the reason I wrote my proof a little bit informal. I am asking that kind of (perhaps) obvious questions, because I am still learning the "manifold language".

Comment: If $\varphi\colon U\to\Bbb R^n$ is a chart, $U\subset M$, then $\varphi\circ f $ makes no sense!

Comment: Ok, $f\circ\varphi^{-1}$. But everything else is correct?